# Combine 2 columns of data

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I would like to merge 2 columns of data in Excel so I still have two columns, but containing all possible variations of the combination. I am really struggling to explain what I mean so hopefully I can explain it graphically.

Assume I have the following 2 columns

```
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  1  +
+-----+-----+
|  B  |  2  +
+-----+-----+
|  C  |  3  +
+-----+-----+
|     |  4  +
+-----+-----+
|     |  5  +
+-----+-----+
```

I would like to merge them all together into two new columns so I am left with the following

```
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  1  +
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  2  +
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  3  +
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  4  +
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  5  +
+-----+-----+
|  B  |  1  +
+-----+-----+
|  B  |  2  +
+-----+-----+
|  B  |  3  +
+-----+-----+
|  B  |  4  +
+-----+-----+
|  B  |  5  +
+-----+-----+
|  C  |  1  +
+-----+-----+
|  C  |  2  +
+-----+-----+
|  C  |  3  +
+-----+-----+
|  C  |  4  +
+-----+-----+
|  C  |  5  +
+-----+-----+
```

I suspect the answer might involve array formulas but I have no idea how to use them.

Is anyone able to help?

Thanks

Comment: You can always achieve such things by creating macros. Is this the same issue discussed [here]?(http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=149917)

Comment: I should have said, I need to use formulas, not Script.

Comment: Uhhhh :-( I'll think about it, but it's gonna be a hard one :-D

Answer (score 0):

Following the scheme:

[image]

And using the formulas:

```
D2 -> =ROUNDDOWN(ROW(C1)/(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11;"<>")+0,1);0)
E2 -> =IF(INDIRECT("A"&(2+D2))<>0;INDIRECT("A"&(2+D2));"")
F2 -> =IF(F1+1>COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11;"<>");1;F1+1)
G2 -> =IF(E2<>"";INDEX($B$2:$B$11;F2);"")
```

and autocomplete...
The column D and F (Index) can be hided...

Answer (score 0):

This solution will repeat column A on an individual level according to the number of items in column B.  This will then repeat column B as a series.

**Formula to repeat Column A**:

```
=INDIRECT("A" & INT((ROW()+COUNTA(B:B))/COUNTA(B:B)))
```

**Formula to repeat Column B**:

```
=INDIRECT("B" & MOD(ROW()-1,COUNTA(B:B))+1)
```

If it helps [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fU-hmdlsDFgabx2G41XLL9GHL5IJx8hUItpQ1Yda5yo/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to a live Google spreadsheet that I threw the formulas in, the empty cells show up blank in Google but they will show up as 0's in Excel